# react-native files inside the android project and execute

Tags: android, react-native, kotlin

Is there a way we can add react-native files inside the android project and execute using an android native code??
The vice versa is possible by using this
https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android

I created the HTML and JS in the asset folder and loaded using WebView by using below.

```
WebView myweb = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
myweb.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
```